# Are there any open design files for an NXP LPC1* breakout board?

Tags: lpc

I would like to build a board for an LPC1* processor. Are there published Eagle layouts for these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MicroBuilder.eu have an Eagle format reference design for the LPC1114.

http://www.microbuilder.eu/Projects/LPC1114ReferenceDesign.aspx

http://www.microbuilder.eu/Projects/LPC1114ReferenceDesign/LPC1114CodeBase.aspx